# Is there any way to add 2 additional field in buy button cart in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, cart, liquid

I'm a new bie in Shopify. 
Is there any way to add 2 additional field in buy button cart in Shopify?
Here's the web site url where buy button is embeded http://www.ohiopma.org/Events/OPMA-Events

My client want 2 required input field (full name and Age) in this cart. Buyer will have to input their name and age before proceed to checkout.

Thanks in Adavance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, line item properties (the ability to pass custom information through to a checkout) aren't yet supported in the Buy Button, or in the [JS Buy SDK](http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/). However, we're currently working on API support to be able to do this from the SDK, which we'll then be able to make available to the Buy Button channel directly.

Comment: @mils No specific date yet - the issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk/issues/105

Comment: Hi rich, I saw from [ https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk/issues/105 ] that this is in v1.0alpha, which is great! Just checking if the plan is still to make it available in the Buy Button channel? Thanks